# ServicePulse showing zero errors but yet there are errors

Tags: nservicebus

Please refer to my attached screenshot.[image: msmq and servicepulse]

I have an "sms" queue that has messages posted to it from a web client using NServiceBus.  Constantly refreshing the MSMQ manager I see the messages appear in the sms queue.  NServiceBus processes them and exceptions are raised (I'm not concerned about the exceptions - I know how to resolve them) and NServiceBus goes through its first and second level retries.  Eventually, the messages end up in the "error" queue, as expected.  However, my concern is that I don't see any of these failed messages showing up in the ServicePulse view.
Here is an excerpt from my endpoint config:

```
<AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
```

The ServiceControl dlls are in place, and the endpoint is showing a heartbeat in the ServicePulse dashboard.

Also of concern is that no messages whatsoever are showing up in the audit queue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Funny, I am facing exactly the same problem today. I will answer your question if I find the answer before you. :) BTW. The Audit queue is only supposed to get succesful messages, so if you only have failed messages that is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here which worked for me: http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/creating-config-file

Apparently ServicePulse forces you to use a centralized error queue for all endpoints. I assumed it would use the error queue defined in the endpoints config, but no such luck.

The default name for the queue is "error". Which means you have 2 choices

1. Rename all your endpoints error queues to "error"
2. Create a config file here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServiceControl\ServiceControl.exe.config containing this:

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: The config file I provided disappeared from the answer... well here it is:     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
          <add key="ServiceBus/ErrorQueue" value="NameOfCentralizedErrorQueue" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>

Comment: Correct. The idea of the architecture behind it is to have a centralized error and audit point for the whole system. ServiceControl feeds off these queues and provides the necessary information to ServicePulse. That's also why the audit and error queues are empty. If you still want to keep a copy of your messages make sure you also configure the AuditLogQueue and the ErrorLogQueue (ServiceBus/ErrorLogQueue and ServiceBus/AuditLogQueue).

Comment: Wait I'm not following.  If I have a queue named "error", and the ServiceControl's default error queue is "error", what exactly would I put into the ServiceControl.exe.config?

Comment: If the queue called error is the one you log to from the service, then your problem might be another one than mine. But be Aware that servicecontrol empties the error queue, which is why you can use the error.log queue to keep the original item.

Comment: @ShawndeWet is everything running on the same machine? Having a centralized error queue in a multi-machine environment means to define the error queue like the following error@machinename in case of MSMQ. So ServiceControl needs to consume this error queue and can forward the processed messages to a log queue i.ex. error.log@machinename. Does that clarify?